# Unexpected type(s): (int, bytes) Possible type(s): (SupportsIndex, SupportsIndex) (slice, Iterable[SupportsIndex] | bytes)

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, warnings, type-hinting

When i wrote a python funtion below:

```
def readinto(self, b: bytearray) -> int:
    n, size = 0, len(b)
    while n < size:
        try:
            b[n] = next(self._it)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        n += 1
    return n
```

I got a waning on b[n] from IDE, which says:

> Unexpected type(s): (int, bytes) Possible type(s): (SupportsIndex,
> SupportsIndex) (slice, Iterable[SupportsIndex] | bytes)

I'm totally confused:  Why the index of array b should be a type of SupportsIndex?  Is there any problem on simple int?

[image]

Comment: I don't get that warning on VSCode, Python 3.10.11

Comment: are you using Pycharm?

Comment: Yes, this is in Pycharm 2023.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in **Pycharm**:

It was present in `2021.2.3` and other versions

*PyCharm `2022.1` do not have this bug.*

But, it looks like that **bug is back as of 2023.2.1 (Community Edition)**

---

Try these workarounds (temporary solutions):

Go to

> `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings`

Or

> `Disable warnings/ ignore warnings`

Comment: So it was a bug, haha. Okay then, I'll create an issue for it and wait for it to be fixed.

Comment: @songofhawk good luck:)